# Почему выводяться только последние элементы массивов?

Tags: php

По какой причине выводятся только последние элементы массивов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
$guns = [
    $automats = [
        'Automat' => 'AK-47',
        'Automat' => 'M4-A1',
        'Automat' => 'Scar',
        'Automat' => 'Tommy gun',
        'Automat' => 'UZI'
    ],
    $pistols = [
        'Pistol' => 'Pistol',
        'Pistol' => 'Deagle',
        'Pistol' => 'USP-4'
    ],
    $granade = [
        'Granade' => 'Smoke granade',
        'Granade' => 'Boom granade',
        'Granade' => 'Teleportation granade'
    ]
];
foreach($guns as $value) {
    echo '<br />';
    foreach($value as $guntype => $gunname) {
        echo $guntype.' => '.$gunname;
    };
};
```

Comment: У вас ключи в массиве все одинаковые: `Automat`, `Pistol`, `Granade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$guns = [
    'Automat' => [
        'AK-47',
        'M4-A1',
        'Scar',
        'Tommy gun',
        'UZI'
    ],
    'Pistol' => [
        'Pistol',
        'Deagle',
        'USP-4'
    ],
    'Granade' => [
        'Smoke granade',
        'Boom granade',
        'Teleportation granade'
    ]
];

foreach($guns as $guntype => $value) {
    echo '<br />';
    foreach($value as $gunname) {
        echo $guntype.' => '.$gunname . '<br />';
    }
};
```